# tokenize error in python

Tags: python, conflict, tokenize

I have this sample program from python-docx library example-extracttext.py to extract text from a docx file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
This file opens a docx (Office 2007) file and dumps the text.

If you need to extract text from documents, use this file as a basis for your
work.

Part of Python's docx module - http://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx
See LICENSE for licensing information.
"""

import sys

from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        document = opendocx(sys.argv[1])
        newfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
    except:
        print(
            "Please supply an input and output file. For example:\n"
            "  example-extracttext.py 'My Office 2007 document.docx' 'outp"
            "utfile.txt'"
        )
        exit()

    # Fetch all the text out of the document we just created
    paratextlist = getdocumenttext(document)

    # Make explicit unicode version
    newparatextlist = []
    for paratext in paratextlist:
        newparatextlist.append(paratext.encode("utf-8"))

    # Print out text of document with two newlines under each paragraph
    newfile.write('\n\n'.join(newparatextlist))
```

It runs fine but when I put another program called tokenize.py (given just below) in the same directory.

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
fo = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
data = fo.read()
print '\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data))
```

It gives following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-extracttext.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docx-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/docx.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 4, in init lxml.etree (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:178742)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/home/sriram/NLP_TOOLS/EDITING_TOOL/NLP/sriram_work/tokenize.py", line 3, in <module>
    import nltk.data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 176, in <module>
    @decorator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 154, in decorator
    if inspect.isclass(caller):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isclass'
```

Please tell me how to resolve this. I want to use both the programs in a single shell script.

Comment: and where is the code for tokenyzer.py?

Comment: I have already provided the code  in 2nd code segment.

Comment: Try to  replace `if inspect.isclass(caller):` with the `if inspect is caller:`.

Comment: @RasikaPerera: Why on Earth would you do that? That's a completely different test, and it's modifying a third party package this shouldn't need modification.